# Streaming data periodically into azure blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

What is the best way to periodically add data (probably csv) to a blob using python?

I have transaction data that I poll from an API, and I'd like to periodically add that transaction data to azure storage so that I can use BI tools, such as PowerBI.

I'm thinking I can schedule a cloud function that Polls the API every day and sends a csv to the azure blob.. would this work?

Comment: Azure function timer trigger? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#python-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like joy pasted, Azure Function provide Timer trigger for python, you could use it to schedule a job.

And Function provides input and output binding to read/write blobs. Also you could use Storage SDK for Python to implement the logic.

Further more information about python binding you could refer to this doc:[Python example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input---python-example). And how to create python function, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python).